# Get source code for a PPA

Tags: ppa, source-code

When I want to get the source code for a package in a PPA, how do I get it?
Is there some "normal" approach, or do I have to contact the developer in question?

Example case: I wanted to look at the changes that were made to compiz in this PPA:
  https://launchpad.net/~bsantos/+archive/ppa

I'm interested in a reference to the version control system, not in a source package, because the source package doesn't tell me what changes the author made.

Comment: Do you need this? https://launchpadlibrarian.net/104780031/compiz_1%3A0.9.7.6-0ubuntu1_1%3A0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1ppa1.diff.gz

Comment: the ppa u have given has only one package!

Comment: @jasmines Yes that looks great! How do I get that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you are in the main page of the PPA containing your package (ex: https://launchpad.net/~bsantos/+archive/ppa) click on "View package details" on the right, then click on the package you need, then click on one of the "Available diffs", and you'll obtain what I provided in my comment.